# Getting specific text to show up in textview

Tags: android, textview

This has been bugging me, I'm a beginner and can't seem to figure this out. Here's my code:

```
package com.example.imhungry;

import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;



public class ImHungry extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_im_hungry);

        final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click
                Random randomGenerator = new Random();
                int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(9);
                String wordToDisplay = wordList[randomInt];
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_im_hungry, menu);
        return true;
    }

    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(9);
    String wordList[] = new String[9];
    {
        wordList[0] = "Mexican";
        wordList[1] = "American";
        wordList[2] = "Barbeque";
        wordList[3] = "Chinese";
        wordList[4] = "Indian";
        wordList[5] = "Italian";
        wordList[6] = "Thai";
        wordList[7] = "Viatnamese";
        wordList[8] = "Middle Eastern";



    }


 String wordToDisplay = wordList[randomInt];




}
```

Basically I am attempting to make the wordToDisplay show up in my textView but I cannot figure out how to do so.

```
 <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:text=""
        tools:context=".ImHungry" />
```

Also,  sorry for asking so many questions, i'm new at this. Thanks!

Comment: your question got nothing with Eclipse. Do not set any tag you can come up with - that's makes follower not quite happy.

Comment: Where is the TextView? Is it supposed to appear in the options menu?

Answer (score 0):

To make your test appear in TextView you have to set it with `setText();`, so basically you have to assign your textview id or tag (add `android:id="@+id/mytextview`) then get that object `TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytextview); tv.setText("foo");` I'd also recommend going through some tutorials on android basics - will help

Answer (score 0):

Add id to the TextView:

```
   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_random_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
    android:text=""
    tools:context=".ImHungry" />
```

In the code do the next:

Add just after the button:

```
final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_random_text);
```

Set the wordToDisplay to the text in the onClick(View v) method

```
textView.setText(wordToDisplay);
```

Answer (score 0):

For efficiency try this:

```
public class ImHungry extends Activity {
    Random mRandomGenerator = new Random();
    TextView mTextView;
    String mWordList[] = new String[] { 
        "Mexican", "American", "Barbeque",
        "Chinese", "Indian", "Italian",
        "Thai", "Viatnamese", "Middle Eastern" };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_im_hungry);

        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click
                mTextView.setText(mWordList[mRandomGenerator.nextInt(9)]);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You can remove the rest of the code.

You only need to create one random number object and you don't need to save the random Integer or corresponding String in local variables, if you only use them once. However it is okay to save them in local variables if you want to improve readability.